# Configure ASP.NET_SessionId cookie expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I just saw in my browser a cookie with the name `ASP.NET_SessionId` and an expiration of "When I close my browser".

From where this expiration time coming, and how can I configure it?

[image: Browser screenshot showing the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie with an expiry of 'When I close my browser']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asp.net sets a cookie which is `NOT PERSISTENT` - meaning you didn't set any Expiration time.

So the expiration time is when you close the browser.

If you set expiration time - it goes from the memory area into the Hard Drive as a file !

<kbd>expiration is set ? yes</kbd>

in Hard Drive as a file.
this is called persistent

<kbd>expiration is set ? no</kbd>

this is called non-persistent as ASP.NET_SessionId cookie in memory.

<kbd>expiration setting - how ?</kbd>

```
Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = "patrick";
Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: How can I configure the expiry time of the cookie am I asking?

Comment: Is ASP.net_sessionid cookie non persistent by default?

Comment: @RockySingh yeah. notice it doesnt have a name - but a const name. once you set expiration , it gets the name of the domain ....

Comment: just one thing more.. I have session state off in my web config then how come this cookie is generated?

Comment: session State is related to "where to store the session"..(not cookie !) in sql ? in mempory ? in another server ?... session state is user in a web farm  - where john can request a page and to get responses from multiple servers... (which needs to be synchronizing sessions !!!). cookie is just to store some information. not related to sessionState.

Comment: @RockySingh the extra properties  of cookieless - is just to where to store the cookie - in URL or not.

Comment: @RockySingh feel free asking more  , if you need something.

Answer (score 1):

HttpCookie has an `Expires` property you can set that to manage cookie lifetime.

If you don't set an expiration this is handled with in session. Therefore the cookie dies with the session.

More information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178194(v=vs.100)